# When $E_D:y^2=x^3+17D^2x$ has even rank?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E:y^2=x^3+17x$ be an elliptic curve.
In this MO page([Infinitely many elliptic curve with twist rank more than $1$ in specific case](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449991/infinitely-many-elliptic-curve-with-twist-rank-more-than-1-in-specific-case)), Nulhomologous's and other's comment reads from parity conjecture, twist $E_D:y^2=x^3+17D^2x$ by odd integer $D$ has always even rank.

But Sage and LMFDB reads $1$.

Where did I go wrong and what is a correct condition of integer $D$ such that $E_D$ has an even rank (admitting parity conjecture) ?

Comment: I would suggest that you learn how to calculate the root number by calculating it as a product of local root numbers like in [this article](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN365956996_0082?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B95%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D). 
For the concrete case here, I suggest to use ```for D in [1,3,5,7,11,13,15,17,19]: E = EllipticCurve([17*D^2,0]); print(D,E.root_number())``` to guess what the right answer is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the root number over $\mathbb{Q}$ of any elliptic curve of the form $y^2=x^3+\alpha x$ for $\alpha\in \mathbb{Q}^*$ using the formulae in section 4B in 
[Density of rational points on isotrivial rational elliptic surfaces](https://msp.org/ant/2011/5-5/p04.xhtml), by Anthony Várilly-Alvarado.

In your case $\alpha=17D^2$, for $D$ odd and square free (if $p^2$ divides $D$, then the elliptic curve $E_D$ and $E_{D/p^2}$ are isomorphic), the root number is $1$ if and only if $D\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ (it is not true what you said about any odd integer $D$). In fact we will show that
$$ W(E_D)=\left(\frac{-1}{D} \right) $$

Using the formulae there, we need to compute first what he calls $W_2(17D^2)$ (and it is the root number at $2$). It is always $-1$, as $v_2(17D^2)=0$ and $17D^2 \equiv 1, 9,15 \pmod{16}$.

Then we compute $W_3(17D^2)=-1=\left(\frac{-1}{3} \right)$ if and only if $3$ divides $D$ (but 9 doesn't, as $D$ is square-free).

Now, following his notation, the number $$R(17D^2)=\left(\frac{-1}{17D^2} \right)W_2(17D^2)W_3(17D^2)(-1)^{v_3(D^2)}=-\left(\frac{-1}{17} \right)W_3(17D^2)=-W_3(17D^2).$$

Now, for the contributions of the other primes, we need to consider only the primes $p>3$ that divide $D$, and then $p^2$ divides $\alpha=17D^2$, and $v_p(\alpha)=v_p(17D^2)=2$, as $p^2$ doesn't divide $D$.

So, we get finally that the root number is
$$W(17D^2)=-R(17D^2)\prod_{p\mid D,p>5} \left(\frac{-1}{p} \right) =W_3(17D^2)\prod_{p\mid D,p>5} \left(\frac{-1}{p} \right)=\prod_{p\mid D} \left(\frac{-1}{p} \right) =\left(\frac{-1}{D} \right) ,$$
which is $1$ if and only if $D\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Another more direct proof, but valid only if $17$ does not divide $D$, is by using the fomulae in [Root number of a quadratic twist of an elliptic curve](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157631/root-number-of-a-quadratic-twist-of-an-elliptic-curve), which in fact is explained in of Rubin's and Silverberg's article [Twists of elliptic curves of rank at least four](http://www.math.uci.edu/%7Easilverb/bibliography/rankfour.pdf). As the conductor $N$ of $E$ given by $y^2=x^3+17x$ is $N=2^617^2$, the root number is $$W(E_D)=\left(\frac{-N}{D} \right)W(E)=\left(\frac{-1}{D} \right)W(E)=\left(\frac{-1}{D} \right),$$
as the root number of $E$ is 1, if $D$ is odd and not divisible by $17$.